# Insertion Sort Access / Usability Issues

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, insert, insertion-sort

```
SortedArrayList<E extends Comparable<? super E>> extends ArrayList<E> {

public SortedArrayList(){
}

public void insertionSort(E a){

    for (int i=1; i<this.size(); i++ )
    {
        E value = this.get(i);
        int j;

        for (j = i; j > 0; j--)
        {
            if (this.get(j - 1).compareTo(value)<0) { 
                break;
            }
            else {
                this.set(j, this.get(j-1));
                //a.set(j-1, a.get(j));
            }
        }

        this.set(j, value);
    }

}
```

}

I have the above custom insertion sort method.

With the following Classes that need to be sorted, as so:

```
    public class User implements Comparable{

private String firstname;

private String surname;
private int numberOfBooksHeld;

@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    int LnComp = surname.compareTo(this.surname);
    if (LnComp != 0) {
        return LnComp;
    }
    else {
        int FnComp = firstname.compareTo(this.firstname);
        return FnComp;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Book implements Comparable {

    private String title;
private String authorFirstName;
private String authorSurname;
private boolean loan;
private User user;

@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    int LnComp = authorSurname.compareTo(this.authorSurname);
    return LnComp;
}
```

I am storying the sortedArrayList in a class called library

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Library {
private final ArrayList<Book> totalBookInventory = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Book> booksOnLoan = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Book> booksInStock = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
...}
```

The totalBookInventory is the sorted ArrayList where the sorted Books are supposed to be stored and UserList is where the sorted user list is supposed to be stored

Im struggling with invoking it from my driver class

i've tried to use:

```
import java.io.*;
```

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Driver {
private final Library l;
private final User u;
private final SortedArrayList s1;

public Driver() {
    this.l = new Library();
    this.u = new User();
    this.s1 = new SortedArrayList();
}
```

I am struggling adding / invoking new Users / Books into InsertionSort method from the driver class, which should then be added to the the totalBookInventory array and userlist.

ive tried:

```
s1.insertionSort(new User(splitString[0], splitString[1], 0));
```

However, this obviously doesn't add to the userList.

```
bookList.insertionSort(new User(splitString[0], splitString[1], 0));
```

and also this code wont access the insertionSort class.

really struggling with accessing and adding into the necessary ArrayList, do I need the ArrayLists to be fields of Driver or? Please help, thank you in Advance

Comment: Every one of your `compareTo` methods is broken, because it doesn't use `o`.  Also, your `insertionSort` method shouldn't take any arguments at all, it should just be `insertionSort()` -- perhaps you should be calling `list.add(new User(...)); list.insertionSort();`

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thats what i thought, however when I try explicitly use either (Book b) or (User u) it wont allow me to do this, comes up with an error. e.g.     Override
    public int compareTo(Book book) {
        int LnComp = authorSurname.compareTo(this.authorSurname);
        return LnComp;
    } --> this doesn't work

Comment: @LouisWasserman I realised that my Book and User classes don't implement Comparable<Object> only Comparable . I think this was the issue in terms of the CompareTo. Howveer im still usure about accessing it, thanks for the help